# Definition of directional derivative: Why does it work?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, multivalued-functions

The definition of the directional derivative in my textbook is

$$
\nabla_{\vec{v}} f = \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\vec{x} + h \vec{v} )-f(\vec{x})}{h}
$$

with $\vec{x} = (x_1, x_2)$ and $\vec{v} = (v_1, v_2)$ (I first want to consider the two variable case).

However, before looking at this definition I tried to come up with it on my own: Say I'm given a function $f(x_1, x_2)$ and wanted to evaluate the directional derivative for a vector $\vec{v}$ for $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = 0$. Similar to the one-variable case I would consider the slope of the secant $\Delta f$
$$
\Delta f = \frac{f(x_1 + v_1, x_2 + v_2) -f(x_1, x_2)}{\Vert \vec{v}\Vert}
$$
so when introducing some real number $h > 0$  which will allow us to make the change in $(x_1, x_2)$ arbitrary small we can  consider the limit
$$
\nabla_{\vec{v}} f = \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\vec{x} + h \vec{v} )-f(\vec{x})}{h\Vert\vec{v}\Vert}
$$
whereby $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ denotes the standard $\mathbb{R}^2$ norm.

Is the latter definition also correct? I doubt it, because if

$$
\nabla_{\vec{v}} f = \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\vec{x} + h \vec{v} )-f(\vec{x})}{h} = L \neq  0 
$$
then

$$
\nabla_{\vec{v}} f = \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\vec{x} + h \vec{v} )-f(\vec{x})}{h\Vert\vec{v}\Vert} = \frac{1}{\Vert \vec{v}\Vert} \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\vec{x} + h \vec{v} )-f(\vec{x})}{h} = \frac{1}{\Vert \vec{v}\Vert} L \neq L.
$$

I hope someone can clarify this for me.

**Edit:** I know that the first definition is more general because  it doesn't require the existence of a  norm but I still don't see why it is correct. Also, in my attempt **I don't assume that $\Vert\vec{v}\Vert = 1$** because I just think of it as the length of the vector. Why is this incorrect?

Comment: Some textbooks make a distinction between directional derivative (that uses $\|v\| =1$) and derivative along a vector.

Comment: Good work! It's only a matter of conventions; I guess your textbook implicitly assumes $\lVert \vec v \rVert=1$. Also, let me remark that both definitions require a norm, because there is a norm in the definition of "limit".

Comment: @PierreCarre doesn't answer my question

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro In "my" definition I don't assume that $\Vert \vec{v} \Vert = 1$, I just take it as the length of the given vector

Comment: @Rhi If you think about it, your definition is indeed equivalent to setting $\|v\| = 1$. If it's not, you just change variables in the limit.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro really, I thought that for the first definition the norm doesn't have to be defined, does it?

Comment: A vector norm is only needed for the definition of the total derivative as far as I know.

Comment: How do you define the "limit" without a norm? (Technically you can, but at least you need a topology. This train of thoughts will lead you far astray into abstract functional analysis, though. It's fascinating, but it is also distracting).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro do you have an explanation to the last question I posted  under Bungo's answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of the directional derivative is indeed correct, or at least it is one way how one could define it. In fact, your definition is equivalent to the one in terms of a unit vector, which intuitively can be explained by noticing that we are only interested in the direction of the vector rather than its magnitude, because when considering the limit, the magnitude of the vector won't matter. Moreover, using your definition (provided a norm exists) one obtains the same results as using the definition in terms of the unit vector.

Let $\overline{v} = \begin{bmatrix} a\\b
\end{bmatrix} $ denote the unit vector and
$\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix} v_1\\v_2 \end{bmatrix} = \overline{v} \cdot 
\lambda, \ 1 < \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ some unnormed vector.

First,
consider only
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h a, y + hb)}{h}
$$
whereby it can be shown that (if you want me to clarify this please say so)$$
\nabla_{\overline{v}}f(x, y) = f_x(x, y) \cdot  a + f_y(x, y) \cdot b
$$

so
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h v_1, y + hv_2)}{h\cdot \|\vec{v}\|}
= \frac{1}{\|\vec{v}\|}\cdot 
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h v_1, y + hv_2)}{h} =  \frac{1}{\|\vec{v}\|}
\cdot \left(   f_x(x, y) \cdot  v_1 + f_y(x, y) \cdot v_2 \right)
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{\|\vec{v}\|}
\cdot \left(   f_x(x, y) \cdot  a\cdot \lambda 
+ f_y(x, y) \cdot b\cdot \lambda \right) 
= \frac{\lambda}{\|\vec{v}\|}
\left(   f_x(x, y) \cdot  a\cdot
+ f_y(x, y) \cdot b\cdot  \right) 
$$

$$
= 
f_x(x, y) \cdot  a\cdot 
+ f_y(x, y) \cdot b.
$$

Now, when there doesn't exist a norm, things are getting more abstract and we no longer have this intuitive interpretation of the directional derivative and hence no longer "care" about the potential factors. Notice however, that when using the first definition you mentioned, there is no unique directional derivative considering one direction, which is an important distinction.

Answer (score 2):

As already observed in the other answers and comments, the two definitions agree up to a harmless multiplicative constant, so they can be used more or less interchangeably.

There is, however, an important property which makes the textbook's definition
$$
\nabla_v f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ f(x+hv)-f(x)}{h}$$
superior to the other, in certain fields of mathematics. With this definition, there is the following linearity property:
$$
\nabla_{av+bw} f(x)=a\nabla_v f(x)+ b\nabla_w f(x),  $$
provided that $f$ is differentiable at $x$. This is one of the building blocks of differential geometry; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2755120/8157).

On the other hand, I have the impression that the definition
$$\nabla_v f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ f(x+hv)-f(x)}{h\lVert v \rVert}$$
is more widely used in applied mathematics. This is probably due to dimensional analysis; if $x$ and $v$ have the units of lenght, then $\nabla_v$ has the correct units of length^{-1}, unlike the previous definition.

Comment: thanks for the additional insights, I still don't understand why this constant (the magnitude of the vector) doesn't matter here, because this gives us different values for the directional derivative.

Comment: @Rhi: Right, and indeed, it does matter. Luckily, we are often much more interested in the *sign* of the derivative, rather than its magnitude. That's the same for both definitions. Also, in practice we almost always compute derivatives with respect to unit vectors (say, $(1, 0,0)$ for $\partial_x$, $(0, 1,0)$ for $\partial_y$ and so on, also in higher dimension).

Comment: hm, still doesn't convince me 100%. Since it does matter, which is then the correct definition, and since it is probably the first, why does the factor in my definition give an incorrect result?

Comment: There rarely is a "correct" definition in mathematics. Especially in higher subjects.

Comment: Ok, but I don't really see why the apparently most commonly used definition yields the "correct" values

Answer (score 1):

You pointed it out yourself, the difference is marginal and just envolves a constant. In particular, the existence of the limit of both definitions is equivalent, they differ only by a factor (which in fact is one, if one restrict directions to unit vectors). Note that if one defines the directional derivative via the gradient, i.e. $(\nabla f(x),v)$, then this only equals the first expression.

Comment: I edited some detail

Comment: That's another point in favor of the first expression. Now that I am thinking about this, the first expression is clearly superior from a purely mathematical standpoint (cfr. this answer and my answer). It is dimensionally wrong, though.

Answer (score 1):

The two definitions are the same if $v$ is a unit vector. So it comes down to what you want "directional derivative" to mean when $v$ is not a unit vector. The textbook definition will give different results for different positive scalar multiples of $v$ (it depends on both the direction and the magnitude of ), and yours will not (yours depends only on the direction of $v$). Both conventions are reasonable, and I've seen both used in textbooks.

This quote from Ted Shifrin's [Multivariable Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047152638X) may be of interest. (He uses the same definition as your textbook.)

**Note:** Ted is a MSE user; hopefully he won't mind me transcribing this excerpt. I'm making this post a CW because the explanation is his, not mine.

---

**Remark** Our terminology [directional derivative] may be a bit misleading. Note that since

> $$\begin{aligned}
> D_{cv}f(a) &= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(a + t(cv)) - f(a)}{t} \\
> &= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(a + (ct)v) - f(a)}{t} \\
> &= c \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(a + (ct)v) - f(a)}{ct} \\
> &= c\lim_{s \to 0}\frac{f(a + sv) - f(a)}{s} \\
> &= cD_v f(a), \\
> \end{aligned}$$
> the directional derivative depends not only on the direction of $v$, but also on its magnitude. It is for this reason that many calculus books require that one specify a *unit* vector $v$. It makes more sense to think of $D_v f(a)$ as the rate of change of $f$ as experienced by an observer moving with instantaneous velocity $v$.

Comment: but what if we don't assume $v$ to be a unit vector?

Comment: If $v$ is not a unit vector, then the textbook's definition will be proportional to $\|v\|$. Yours will not, because you normalize by $\|v\|$. So, according to the textbook definition, the directional derivative in the "direction" of $2v$ is twice as large as in the direction of $v$.

Comment: but why is mine incorrect, i.e. where is by thinking mistake

Comment: @Rhi Yours is not incorrect, it just uses a different convention. Both definitions are perfectly reasonable. The important thing is that if you're reading someone else's work (textbook etc.) that you know which definition they're using.

Comment: I'm just not really understanding why one can neglect the magnitude of the vector, since in analogy to the one-variable case, we consider the total change in the variables, i.e. the distance between two points, which would correspond to involving the magnitude of the vector. That's the  only thing I don't really get